# evil mode: switch back to normal mode automatically after inaction

Tags: evil

I was wondering if anyone has ever looked at a way to switch back to normal mode automatically after inaction?  In Vim, there are several methods to do that, such as:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/To_switch_back_to_normal_mode_automatically_after_inaction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function and idle timer will force evil back into
normal state in all buffers after an idle delay of 30 seconds
(which you can adjust as you like):

```
(defun evil-normalize-all-buffers ()
  "Force a drop to normal state."
  (unless (eq evil-state 'normal)
    (dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
      (set-buffer buffer)
      (unless (or (minibufferp)
                  (eq evil-state 'emacs))
        (evil-force-normal-state)))
    (message "Dropped back to normal state in all buffers")))

(defvar evil-normal-timer
  (run-with-idle-timer 30 t #'evil-normalize-all-buffers)
  "Drop back to normal state after idle for 30 seconds.")
```

Comment: perfect! this works well

Comment: @Dan this worked well for me too, but I have two questions:
1. Doesn't the `unless (eq evil-state 'normal) ...` mean the "for loop" over buffers will be done if the _current_ buffer is not in normal state? How would one modify this logic so that the for loop was done periodically regardless of the current buffer state, and all non-normal buffers were dropped into normal state?
2. How would I do the above so that only the buffers in `insert` state were reverted to normal state?
Thanks in advance for any answers/pointers you can give me!